# Check absolute file path if exist not working in C++

Tags: c++, windows, ifstream

I know there are similar questions to this but it did not solve my problem.

I used std::ifstream and PathFileExist but it always returns false and my error handler GetLastError() always gives the message

```
"The system cannot find the file specified"
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and i have tested files in different directories using absolute path to remove the possibility of "Permission" and "wrong path" problems.

Here's my code snippet.

NOTE: ErrorExit is just a wrapper that uses GetLastError() to display error messages.

Attempt A

```
if (std::ifstream((LPCWSTR)"C:\\Windows\\write.exe"))
{
    // do some thing if file is found
}   
else
    ErrorExit(TEXT("ifstream"));
```

or Attempt B

```
std::ifstream f;
f.open(L"C:\\Windows\\write.exe", ios::in);

if (f.is_open())
{
    // do something if file is open
}
```

or to check permission first Attempt C

```
if (_waccess(L"C:\\Windows\\write.exe", 04) == 0)

    if (std::ifstream((LPCWSTR)"C:\\Windows\\write.exe"))
    {
         // do some thing if file is found
    }   
    else
        ErrorExit(TEXT("ifstream"));
}
else
    ErrorExit("_waccess");
```

I tried different string conventions already like:

```
L"C:\\Windows\\write.exe"
(LPCWSTR)"C:\\Windows\\write.exe"
_T("C:\\Windows\\write.exe")
TEXT("C:\\Windows\\write.exe")
```

still no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your project UNICODE?

Comment: @sameerkn Yes it is.

Comment: **Stop casting**.  Get rid of the `(LPCWSTR)` casts.  You are not magically turning a non-wide string to a wide string by casting.  Use the correct string types --  all you're doing when you cast is to shut the compiler up concerning errors.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie As you can see in the statements that i've tried, even without no cast didn't work.

Comment: @winux What I'm saying is that you shouldn't have even tried casting.  It is a non-starter.  Even  the compiler told you this, but you ignored it and instead put a cast on the string.  Again, use the correct string types.  If you have an issue after you have removed the cast **and** the program compiles successfully, then let's look at the issue.

Comment: `std::ifstream f;`  This accepts only 8-bit char type strings for the file name.  If you are calling a function with a string, and you get a compiler error concerning that you cannot convert a narrow character string to a wide character string, either 1) use the correct string types, or 2) Find a function that accepts the string types you're using.  Casting is not the solution.

Comment: Use `wifstream` instead of `ifstream`.

Comment: @sameerkn That is the correct solution. Well that along with a change to actually using `wstring`s instead of trying yo cast to them. Could you post as an answer?

Comment: `std::wifstream(_T("C:\\Windows\\write.exe"));` would also be correct. Since `_T("C:\\Windows\\write.exe")` would create a `wstring`.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're have windows specific code ( with LPCWSTR, etc )

So use Win API

```
#include <windows.h>
...
if (GetFileAttributesW(L"C:\\windows\\write.exe") == -1)
  file_not_found(); // file does not exist
else
  file_exists(); // do some thing if file is found
```